# iphone - core data model

Tags: iphone, database-design, core-data

I am new to core data. I am banging my head on the wall trying to understand how should I design the data model for this application.

I have to create a database for books.

```
Books have the following characteristics:
.englishName
.italianName
.frenchName
.spanishName
.number
```

Books can be of two kind: free or non-free.
Books can be sold individually or in bundles.
A bundle can represent a bunch of books.
A book can be in one or more bundles.

What I need:

1. The ability to mark as paid a
   bundle or/and book.
2. the ability to retrieve all non-free or all free
   books, all books from a bundle, all
   books that were bought.

How I imagine this could be done: I would create 3 entities: Bundle, Product and Type and make all products bundles, I mean, a bundle with 1 product or with multiple products.

```
Bundle
.Number
.Paid
-relation to product (fromBundle) to-many


Product
.nameEN
.nameIT
.nameFR
.nameSP
.Number
-fromBundle (relation to Bundle) to-many
-fromType (relation to Type)


Type
.kind
-relation to Product... to-many
```

But I am not sure this is not the way, simply because there's no way to define a bundle name in all 4 languages and if I add those attributes to the bundle, I will end with a lot of redundancy...

please help meeeeeee! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  may be overcomplicating this by introducing Product and Type - all you should really need are the Book and Bundle entities, with a many-to-many relationship between them. Then, to deal with the use cases you presented:

1. Marking a bundle or book paid: for a book, simply mark the book paid; for a bundle, mark all its books paid.
2. For data retrieval:

   - To retrieve all non-free or all free books, just get instances of the Book entity with the `free` attribute set to the appropriate value (or the `price` value zero or nonzero, depending on how you're storing this attribute)
   - To retrieve all books from a given bundle, just call `[bundle books]` - the many-to-many relationship gives you this directly
   - To retrieve all books that were bought, just look for books marked `paid`

This way, you can keep your four name attributes on the Book itself and not worry about them (unless you have to name Bundles, but those should be distinct names anyway). Furthermore, it's conceptually simple - you don't have to worry about what precisely constitutes a Product or semantics of that manner.

Comment: but this is the problem. If I have Bundles and Books, each one has to have the same 2 attributes (Price and Paid) on every book and bundle, as the user can buy one or the other and if, for example, a bundle is bought and I pay the bundle as PAID I am not sure how will I know if a book from the said was bought, unless I mark the book as bought after a bundle is bought. Keeping it working like this is not convincing me that this is the right path. Remember that books and bundles have different prices and in my head are different stuff. If you still see I am complicating, I appreciate if you...

Comment: ... (continues)... can be a little bit more specific on how it should be designed... thanks.

Comment: ... (continues) ... ah, and just to clarify a little bit more. Products and bundles have the same number system, I mean, imagine five books: book 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. Now imagine that number 6 is a bundle, that is equal to books 1, 2 and 3... and 7 is a bundle that is composed of books 3 and 4. I imagined this way because if I number bundles and books with different systems, when a user taps on a table view where they are all listed, I have to check if that index is a book of bundle. If both have the same numbering, I just forward the number to the entity and it tells what it is.

Comment: The reason I kept the `paid` attribute on the Book in my design was that (I presume) you can buy a book outside of a bundle, or even buy all the books in a bundle separately, without buying the bundle itself. So yes, if you mark a bundle `paid` you should mark all its books `paid` as well.